# I am a ? I fly high

Tags: riddle

I fly high with various colors on me.

But most of the time I sit in a corner and not fly.

I hate rain. And I usually don't come out during a rainy day.

A sling of my hair is always long enough to touch the ground.

At times I have a tail.

Who am I?

Comment: I guess the downvotes (not from me btw) are for being too easy...

Comment: @ rand al'thor --- I think so too. Lesson learnt!!    :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are a

> kite

I fly high with various colors on me.

> Kites are colorful.

But most of the time I sit in a corner and not fly.

> They'll be kept indoors most of the time.

I hate rain. And I usually don't come out during a rainy day.

> You can't fly a kite in the rain.

A sling of my hair is always long enough to touch the ground.

> The kite string.

At times i have a tail.

> Kites can have tails hanging off them.

Comment: Damn, 20 seconds too slow! :-)

Comment: guess the 20 seconds was due to the delay in network connection... :)

Comment: i thought of peacock. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are

> Doctor Who.
>
> No, really, go with me on this.  More specifically, you are the fourth incarnation, as portrayed by the inestimable [Tom Baker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Baker).

I fly high with various colors on me.

> Doctor Who is well known for flying in his T.A.R.D.I.S in all his incarnations, but the fourth Doctor in particular is well-known for the multi-coloured scarf he wears.

But most of the time I sit in a corner and not fly.

> The Doctor actually spends relatively little of his screen time in the T.A.R.D.I.S., as his adventures are typically on the ground.

A sling of my hair is always long enough to touch the ground.

> The Fourth Doctor was well known for his long, curly hair.  If one was to weave a sling from his hair (if one had a reason to wish to do so.  If the Daleks were to, say, build a giant mechanised robot to threaten the world and the Doctor needed something with which to fling a rock at it), then one could be quite certain that such a sling would easily be long enough to touch the ground.

At times I have a tail.

> Tom Baker, the actor who portrayed the Fourth Doctor, also was an actor in The Winter's Tale (1968), The Canterbury Tales (1972), The Tales of Aesop (1990), and another production of The Canterbury Tales (2000).  He has had, in fact, several tales.

I hate rain. And I usually don't come out during a rainy day.

> [image]
>
> (See?  Not a good look.)

Comment: It's always sad to see a riddle with only one full answer posted.  So I posted another, to keep it company.  :)